# XPath : Extract the text located after a specific string of characters

Tags: html, wordpress, xpath

I am looking to extract the text located after "Cashback & codes promo" on this code :

```
<h1 class="title title--sec color-black col-xs-12 merchant__title hide-tablet nopadding bold-text"> Cashback &amp; codes promo Direct Energie</h1>
```

I can only extract the h1 tag in its entirety with this code :

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `substring-after` function:

```
substring-after(/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1,
                'Cashback & codes promo ')
```

Note the space included at the end of the substring.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0 we can try using `replace`:

```
replace(/html/body/div[5]/div[5]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1,
        '^.*Cashback & codes promo\s*(.*)$'
        '$1')
```